# Ruby 1.8.7: Concurrent TCP/IP Connections

Tags: ruby, concurrency, tcp, benchmarking

I'm trying to open as many `TCPSocket`s as possible to some remote benchmark boxes.
For example, I'm starting 64 forks, each with 100 threads/connections (`TCPSocket.new`)

It confuses me that I cannot open more than ~500-600 "ESTABLISHED" connections at the same time, besides using *very* good machines (32 cores, 64 GB RAM,..), and of course I also made sure that the sysctl settings are fine (and ulimit -n is at 100000).

I'm checking the connections using:

```
netstat -an | awk '/^tcp/ {print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

and this gives me something like:

```
513 ESTABLISHED
 21 LISTEN
  2 CLOSE_WAIT
```

Now, I really doubt that this problem is due to hardware/latency/OS. 
I also tried to increase the number of clouds that I'm using as remote benchmark boxes, but this didn't increase the established connections so I'm sure it must be a client problem.

Further, it seems like the 500-600 connections that I establish will just "hang". No data seems to arrive at the servers, except I'm lowering the amount of forks/threads on the client substantially.

Do you guys see any bottleneck from a Ruby point of view?

I'm using MRI 1.8.7 (I know it's not supported any longer).

EDIT:
Might this be related to epoll/poll/select?

EDIT 2:
Is it possible to rebuild Ruby MRI 1.8.7 with a different FD_SETSIZE like 65353?
Would this solve the problem?

Comment: 9 years later, did you manage to solve it?